# every geodesic in upper half plane can be moved a range A?

Tags: dynamical-systems, hyperbolic-geometry

I read https://fse.studenttheses.ub.rug.nl/20174/1/bMATH_2019_DePooterJS.pdf

There is such an explanation in this article. By considering a $SL(2, \mathbb{Z})$action every geodesic on upper half plane can move the geodesic which is beginning point $u_{-\infty}$ and end points $u_{\infty}$ as follows: $0<\left|u_{-\infty}\right| \leq 1$ and $\left|u_{\infty}\right| \geq \infty$ and both are on opposite sides of the imaginary axis. Denote this set of geodesics by $A$. $A$ is the set of geodesic with  points $u_{-\infty}$, $u_{\infty}$ belongs to $u_{-\infty} \in (0,1] \text { and } u_{\infty} \in (- \infty, -1]$ or $u_{-\infty} \in(-1,0] \text { and } u_{\infty} \in[1, \infty)$

I think that the power of $\tau=\left[\begin{array}{ll}1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{array}\right]$ is not sufficient because geodesics with the distance between the starting point$u_{-\infty}$ and the endpoint $u_{\infty}$ is less than 2 cannot move to $A$.

How can we think about moving all geodesics in the upper half-plane to $A$ by considering approximate $SL(2, \mathbb{Z})$action?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your question is very unclearly written. I have no idea what the points $u_{\pm \infty}$ are, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the comments the points ±∞ are on real axis 
\begin{equation}
u_{-\infty} \in(-1,0] \text { and } u_{\infty} \in[1, \infty)
\end{equation} or
\begin{equation}
u_{-\infty} \in (0,1] \text { and } u_{\infty} \in (- \infty, -1]
\end{equation}

Comment: And no other restrictions? Then the claim you are trying to prove is simply false.

Comment: we restrict ourselves to those that do not go to ∞ in forward or backward time, i.e. those geodesics that are not vertical lines. Given an oriented geodesic u in E, the corresponding half-circle in H will have two end points on the real axis.

Comment: If  this is all then the claim is false. Why are you trying to prove it?

Comment: Because I didn't know if it would hold or not.
I'm interested in geodesic flow on modular surface via continued fraction.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that using only $\tau$, it is not possible to make any two points on $\mathbb{R}$ lie in the respective intervals. This problem is possible exactly if it is possible to achieve that the points have distance at least one between each other.

If you also allow
$$
\sigma = \begin{pmatrix}0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix},
$$
then it might be possible:

If the Euclidean distance between $u_{-\infty}$ and $u_{\infty}$ is at least 1, you are done. Otherwise apply $\tau$ until both points are inside the unit circle and then apply $\sigma$. This will increase their (Euclidean distance) as
$|\sigma u_{-\infty} - \sigma u_{\infty} | = |u_{-\infty}  - u_{\infty}|/{|u_{\infty}u_{-\infty}|} > |u_{-\infty}  - u_{\infty}|$.

I work out the details for why this increases enough below:

We note that for $u \in (0,1)$ we have $\sigma(u) = -1/u$. We will also use the function $f= \tau \circ \sigma \circ \tau \circ \sigma$, which is described by $f(u) = 1/(1-b)$, (check this). In terms of distances, if $u,v \in (0,1)$, then
$$
d(\sigma(u),\sigma(v)) = \frac{d(u,v)}{uv}
$$
and
$$
d(f(u),f(v)) = \frac{d(u,v)}{(1-u)(1-v)}.
$$
We claim that no matter how $u,v$ are distributed on $(0,1)$, we can apply either $\sigma$ or $f$ to double their distance. Therefore by repeatedly applying $f$ and $\sigma$, we can increase the distance to above 1 at which point we can apply $\tau$ until the endpoints lie in the positions asked in the question. We show the claim by a case distinction:

Case 1: If $d(u,v) \geq 1/2$, then one of $u,v$ has to be at most $1/2$, so $uv \leq 1/2$. Then $d(\sigma(u),sigma(v)) \geq d(u,v)/(1/2) = 2d(u,v)$.

Case 2: $d(u,v) < 1/2$. Without loss of generality let $u \geq v$.

Case 2a: $u \geq 3/4$. Then $v > 1/4$ and $(1-u)(1-v) < 1/4 \cdot 3/4 = 3/8 < 1/2$. Then $d(f(u),f(v)) = d(u,v)/((1-u)(1-v)) > d(u,v)/(1/2) = 2 d(u,v) $.

Case 2b: $u < 3/4$. Then $v<1/4$ and $uv < 3/4 \cdot 1/4 < 1/2$. Then $d(\sigma(u),\sigma(v)) = d(u,v)/(uv) > 2 d(u,v)$.

Comment: Sorry for the late to reply..
Why does this inequality hold?
$\left|\sigma u_{\infty}-\sigma u_{\infty}\right|=\left|u_{-\infty}-u_{\infty}\right| /\left|u_{\infty} u_{\infty}\right|>\left|u_{-\infty}-u_{\infty}\right|$ .

Comment: If $|u_{\infty}| < 1$ and $|u_{-\infty}| < 1$, then dividing any number by $|u_{\infty}u_{-\infty}| $ will increase that number.

Comment: that's true 
Is this a monotonic increase, so it will eventually become larger than one?

Comment: Actually the argument is not complete. if you have a monotonely increasing sequence, it does not necessarily have to become larger than one eventually. (it could for instance approximate 1/2). I think one would need to think a bit more about it to find out why it goes over one eventually.

Comment: yes ... I'd like to be more precise in discussing when it will be greater than 1, but I'm trying to figure out how to approach that.
But I'm not sure if it's just inequality evaluation.

Comment: I added a way to prove it. If you want to try to prove it yourself, you could (before looking at the solution I give) consider the action of $\tau \circ \sigma \circ \tau\circ \sigma$ (together with the action of $\sigma$.